# How can I make Xfce click when changing the volume?

Tags: xfce, volume-control

In Unity, when I change the volume, I'll see a notification and hear a click sound to indicate the current volume.

In Xfce, there's a notification too, but no click. I want to hear a click too. How can I get this done?